# Pandas Install Issue

Tags: python, pandas

I've run `pip install pandas` and seemed to get a ton of warnings but by the end everything seemed to have installed successfully.  I've also run `pip install requests`.

When I call a function with this line:

```
getTeamRoster("http://modules.ussquash.com/ssm/pages/leagues/Team_Information.asp?id=11325")
```

I get this error (seems not to like the read_html call and wants me to install lxml?):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SquashScraper.py", line 51, in <module>
    main()
  File "SquashScraper.py", line 48, in main
    getTeamRoster("http://modules.ussquash.com/ssm/pages/leagues/Team_Information.asp?id=11325")
  File "SquashScraper.py", line 39, in getTeamRoster
    tables = pd.read_html(requests.get(teamURL).content)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 865, in read_html
    parse_dates, tupleize_cols, thousands, attrs, encoding)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 718, in _parse
    parser = _parser_dispatch(flav)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 677, in _parser_dispatch
    raise ImportError("lxml not found, please install it")
ImportError: lxml not found, please install it
```

Any ideas what's going on here?

Happy to provide more info if needed.

Thanks,
bclayman

Edit to add:

pip install got me:

```
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1 Command /usr/local/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/m_/v2nkdbd935l6zwky8jm1g68r0000gn/T/pip_bu‌​ild_ben/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(file).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), file, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/m_/v2nkdbd935l6zwky8jm1g68r0000gn/T/pip-fn3n3u-record/install-recor‌​d.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/m_/v2nkdbd935l6zwky8jm1g68r0000gn/T/pip_build_ben/lxml
```

Comment: read the last line: `lxml not found, please install it`.

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install python-lxml`

Comment: pip install got me: error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

Command /usr/local/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/m_/v2nkdbd935l6zwky8jm1g68r0000gn/T/pip_build_ben/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/m_/v2nkdbd935l6zwky8jm1g68r0000gn/T/pip-fn3n3u-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/m_/v2nkdbd935l6zwky8jm1g68r0000gn/T/pip_build_ben/lxml

Comment: @bshuster13 i don't have apt-get (apparently) :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that you get the following error message:

```
ImportError: lxml not found, please install it
```

That means you need to install `python-lxml` package on Linux.

#### on Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get -y install python-lxml
```

#### On Fedora

```
sudo yum -y install python-lxml
```

#### On Mac

```
brew install libxml2
brew install libxslt
STATIC_DEPS=true sudo pip install lxml
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm on a mac so tried with pip and got the error I commented above :(

Comment: do you have `clang` installed? check it with `which clang`, what is the output?

Comment: output is "/usr/bin/clang"

Comment: am using python 3 fwiw

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a Mac, you have to download and install the developer tools, which can be achieved with this command:

```
xcode-select --install
```

I had the same error before doing so when I did `pip install lxml`